# Can I remove an object from my scene?

Tags: ios, arkit

Relatively new to ARKit, I was wondering if there's a way to remove a 3D object after it has been placed in a scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this function:

Swift:

```
node.removeFromParentNode()
```

Objective-C

```
[node removeFromParentNode];
```

Comment: Yeah I understand the node.removeFromParent() method. What I want to do is be able to remove an object AFTER it has appeared on the screen

Comment: This method allows you to remove an object after it has been placed in the scene, is there something else I'm missing out on?

Comment: yeah nevermind I'm just a clueless newbie, this works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Alan, thank you so much for your detailed answers! I and my team stuck on an issue for days ah :/ I posted an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662318/arkit-apply-filter-cifilter-to-a-specific-part-vertex-of-an-arfaceanchor Would love your suggestions!

Comment: @RoiMulia I'm sorry but i'm not really familiar with the face detection side of AR.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the documentation of [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit), [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit) and their basic classes.

You need to remove a node from the *scene graph* if you don't want it to appear on screen. You need to remove it from its parent node. Read more about it in [SCNNode - Managing the Node Hierachy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode#1655182) in Apples documentation.

Comment: Yeah I understand the node.removeFromParent() method. What I want to do is be able to remove an object AFTER it has appeared on the screen

Comment: So you want to check when an object was first rendered?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an object(SCNNode) from your Scene view, you can use Long Press Gesture. Just add the below code in your *viewDidLoad*.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = 
[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
action:@selector(handleRemoveObjectFrom:)];
longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
[self.sceneView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

Then handle your gesture recognizer method like below,

```
- (void)handleRemoveObjectFrom: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}
CGPoint holdPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.sceneView];
NSArray<SCNHitTestResult *> *result = [self.sceneView hitTest:holdPoint
                                                      options:@{SCNHitTestBoundingBoxOnlyKey: @YES, SCNHitTestFirstFoundOnlyKey: @YES}];
if (result.count == 0) {
    return;
}

SCNHitTestResult * hitResult = [result firstObject];
[[hitResult.node parentNode] removeFromParentNode];

}
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Thanks